# FCM - Message Not Displayed in Header

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I'm trying to implement FCM on my apps. The tutorial source was from [here](http://shubhank101.github.io/iOSAndroidChaosOverFlow/2016/06/Implementing-FCM-(-Firebase-Cloud-Messaging-)-in-Android-App).

The Push Notification was delivered successfully, but why isn't the message displayed in the header? (*just like when receiving WhatsApp message*). It just shows **silently** in the back list (*after we scroll down the header*). Also the push notification doesn't produce any sounds.

Here're my code :

**AndroidManifest.xml** :

```
<service android:name="com.myapps.TokenService">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service android:name="com.myapps.FCMMessageReceiverService">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

**FCMMessageReceiverService.java** :

```
public class FCMMessageReceiverService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    Log.d("Notification Received",remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    sendSnackbar(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}

private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 , intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
}

 private void sendSnackbar(String messagebody)
 {


 }
}
```

**TokenService.java** :

```
public class TokenService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        //super.onTokenRefresh();
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.w("notification", refreshedToken);
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    }
}
```

Comment: did you enabled Google cloud messaging api in developer console

Comment: @RahulChaudhary yes, if not, i will not receive push notif

Answer (score 0):

```
<service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Just add two attributes `android:enabled` and `android:exported` as shown above in `AndroidManifest.xml`